# Maximum call stack size exceded

Tags: javascript, ios, encryption

I am trying to download encrypted pictures and decrypt them using RNcryptor within a Javascript web application and place them within the html of my app. Everything works perfectly except for when pictures are larger in size and cause the call stack to be exceeded.

This error does not occur when to and from devices such as the Iphone, but when I try to send them to the web app, I get this error from the Iphone 6+ but no other device

This is my function used to convert a byte array to base64 string:

```
function encode(data)
{
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,data);
    return btoa(str).replace(/.{76}(?=.)/g,'$&\n');
}
```

Is there a more call stack efficient way to convert the data? I am willing to sacrifice speed if necessary.

Comment: To avoid this, you may resize the image first (below 1024px) before start a encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening on only the Iphone 6 (and I assume it is mainly with pitcures made using its camera) is because the file you are sending is to large. This error probably would not occur with an older model Iphone such as the 5 or the 4 because of the picture quality.

The way that I would fix this is in your app where the picture is originally being encoded and placed on the database, I would resize it before doing so.